# Get nth line before a pattern then output to an excel column

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm working with thousands of config files and I'm trying to output all Ip Adresses into an Excel column.

The files look like this :

```
[Group1]
    GatewayIp=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    IpAddress=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    NetMask=xxx.xxx.xxx.x
    Port=xxx
    Connected=Yes
```

So far I've come up with this code:

```
#Ip Address
$ip = Select-String -Path "$location" -Pattern "    Connected=Yes" -Context 3,0 |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Line,$_.Context.PreContext}
$ip = $ip -replace "    IpAddress=" -replace ""
$row = $i
$Column = 3
$workbook.Cells.Item($row,$column)= "$ip"
```

The issue is that the code above displays all 3 lines before the match and I only want the "IpAddress=" line.

What would be the correct syntaxe to get that ?

Comment: There is a PowerShell module for working with INI files [PsIni](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/2.0.3). That might help making your life easier.

Comment: Found the solution myself :). { $_.Line,$_.Context.PreContext[0].Trim()}